# Drop down won't show options with value greater than 20

Tags: jquery

This is very very strange and I'm not really sure what is happening here. I'm going to my best to explain.

I have a select menu and in that menu I am narrowing results so it will only show what is needed for that specific module. To do that I'm grabbing the needed values and only showing those options that have those values. Everything seemed to be working fine except if I have a value beyond 20.

At start I can show all the values, I have 70 of them, but as soon as they're hidden I cannot get a value past 20 to show even manually.

In the console I tried a few things to try and get it to show up. (I am using the last in my list because it is easy to spot)

```
$("select[name='Type'] option[value='70']").show().prop('disabled', false);
```

This is changing the html to

```
<option value="70" style="display: block;">Title Form Availability</option>
```

and getting rid of the `display:none;`, but it is still not showing in my select menu.

I can write the same code for any value up to 20 and it will show on the screen.

Is there a max value that an option tag can have? If that's true why can I make them all show when the screen first loads?

I am beyond confused as to why and any help is appreciated!

I even have a jsFiddel showing what's happening 
http://jsfiddle.net/005x7wye/

Comment: Your jsFiddle just works fine for me. I can select option 20 and 70. Tested on: Google Chrome Versión 39.0.2171.99 m, FF 33.1.1, FF 35.0 (http://i.imgur.com/7fauSKb.png)

Comment: @Tobías I'm in the same version of Chrome. I see what's happening now, the height on the options are all weird. It's only seeing the first twenty in the list and adding the height to the select menu if those are there, but anything after the first twenty it is not adding the height, thus making it seem like they are not there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functions doesn't work in some browsers for `option` elements. Since the rendering is not triggered for the `select` item the resulting size is incorrect.

A workaround to fix this is add and remove the options using the [`.remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)/[`.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) and [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)/[`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) functions.

For example:

```
var options = [];

$("select[name='FormTypeId'] option").each(
    function() {
        options.push($(this).detach());
    }
);

$("select[name='FormTypeId']").prepend(options[0]);
$("select[name='FormTypeId']").prepend(options[20]);
$("select[name='FormTypeId']").prepend(options[70]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/005x7wye/1/